# How to translate “window switching” in the context of compression algorithms?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

I’m wondering how the term *window switching* is translated into German. For those wondering, it’s a term used in computer science to describe *a popular method for pre-echo suppression, particularly in the case of MDCT-based algorithms.*

I was thinking about *Fenster* or *Intervall* for window, but I’m not 100 % sure if this is correct in this context.

Switching pretty much got me. Maybe *wechseln* oder *tauschen* could fit, but I’m not sure either.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for any remaining questions about how it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience from a neighbouring field, *window* in this sense is generally translated to ***Fenster*** in German, which is confirmed, e.g., by the [German Wikipedia article on *Fensterfunktion*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fensterfunktion).

Going from what a one-minute Internet search told me about the method, I would strongly prefer ***wechseln*** over *tauschen,* since the latter implies that both windows are used all the time, but only their place of usage is changed when the *Tauschen* happens. In this context, I would consider the difference between *wechseln* and *tauschen* equivalent to that between the English *to switch* (or *to change)* and *to swap.*

However, going by my one-minute Internet research, I would also use a totally different approach to describe the method, namely something along the lines of ***adaptive Fensterwahl*** or ***Fensteradaption***, since the essence of the method is not the changing of windows per se, but adapting them to the situation (theoretically, the window could not change at all when this method is applied, in the unlikely case that one window is the best choice for all the data – in this case no window is switched, but its still adaptive).

After I wrote those lines, I did a little more research and found that the technique in question was originally [published by a German in German](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/fau/professor/edler/publications) in a paper titled *Codierung von Audiosignalen mit überlappender Transformation und **adaptiven Fensterfunktionen**.*